# how to recognize particular text and replace that text with other text inside image in android?

Tags: android

My task is to recognize particular text inside an image. Then replace that recognized text with other text in image. But I'm not getting any solution for this in android. It will be great for any suggestions or answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv sdk for image  processing and recognize the text in the image
check this link [openc cv for android](https://opencv.org/android/)

Comment: Thanks @Masoud Darzi, using that opencv we can recognize the text but I didn't find replacing my text with that recognized text inside image. If it is documented in the same could you please send me the link.

Comment: @NeerajaAndroid "Replacing text" is pretty broad. Text isn't a "field" in an image, it's just a bunch of pixels. If you can identify the image region containing text you can use normal image functionality to operate on that region, but replacing text *well* would require removing the original text, restoring the background, and writing new anti-aliased text back.

Comment: @NeerajaAndroid  as Dave Newton said it's another concept for having a new image with new text. I will tell you if find any solution ...